# getMap() in onCreate(), created from layout gives nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, supportmapfragment

This my code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Inside onCreate() method:(I have only this at onCreate(), aside a bundle creation and variables asignation, using that bundle.)

```
FragmentManager myFM = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment myMAPF =(SupportMapFragment)myFM.
      findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
map=myMAPF.getMap();//Exception at this line
```

Layout:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Manifest:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="myapikey" />
```

I have to mention that when i generated the api key I copied the debug.keystore file and stored in a more convenient location, and then generated it. I did it again with the original file in the original location, and returned the same SH1, however, so I didnt generated another API key. Have activated the interruptor in the API Access page.

I have seen some answer asking the same thing before, and I have tried a lot of their solutions... without luck.

I am running the app on a device with Android version 4.0, via USB, from Eclipse.

Anyone can help me to find where is the error? Thank you.

EDIT

Sorry, forgot the StackTrace

```
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at mypackage.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:73)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

I just noticed a strange thing, in the first line of the stacktrace puts twice the full package of my app...why is this happening?

Comment: please post the log, including the full exception stack trace.

Comment: post the complete onCreate function code

Comment: It is probably because the map object is not yet ready. Look at the demo APIs, they use a callback to tell when it is ready.

Comment: What is `map` in your code? Can't you post full code ?

Comment: No...I am sorry but I cant. map is a GoogleMap instance GoogleMap map; A global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Map is not yet available... You can use something like the following method to determine if Play Services are available before making use of them (I would call it in onActivityCreated, rather than onCreate) :

```
protected boolean isPlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return (true);
    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
        // deal with error
    } else {
            // maps is not available
    }

    return (false);
}
```

Also, your Fragment needs to implement the Callbacks required by the Play Services (interfaces GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks and GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener :

```
    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(context, "Connected to location services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected from location services. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
     * Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        SomeActivity,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**
This is how I use it in my activity containing the map fragment :

```
if (isPlayServicesAvailable()) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_map_fragment);
}
```

and in the Fragment :

```
if (getMap() != null) {
    GoogleMap map = getMap();
    // do things with the map
}
```

This should get you going ;-)

Comment: Im going to try this.

Comment: Well...I thought it was ok because isPlayServicesAvailable() returned false, because I havent got the latest google play services instaled. I got back today to do it, now its up to date...and still I got a null pointer exception...

Comment: Does your Fragment extend MapFragment (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html) ?

Comment: Turned out to be a lacking permission. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that you found the root of the problem ;)