# fManager.getFragmentById() returns null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, supportmapfragment

I asked a question like this one the other day... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541681/getmap-in-oncreate-created-from-layout-gives-nullpointerexception/19542071#19542071). I marked it as resolved, because the mistake was that isPlayServicesAvailable() returned false, because I had not the up to date Google Play Services. I have them now...but still NPE.

The code:

```
GoogleMap map;
FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);//after this, fragment is null
SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)fragment;
map=supportmapfragment.getMap();//Got exception here
```

In the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I get this Exception:

```
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at mypackage.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:73)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-23 13:54:53.230: E/AndroidRuntime(6786):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

How can I have my map working...?

Comment: Refer this question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762266/findfragmentbyid-always-returns-a-null

Answer (score 0):

try -

```
GoogleMap map;
FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);;
map=supportmapfragment.getMap();//Got exception here
```

plus change the fragment declaration on the xml to

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
/>
```

Comment: Well I cant help you any farther without more code, if you want more help publish your code...
Btw try and check this post for more help - 
http://dummiesnotes.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/create-android-project-google-map-v2.html